# Flip window c#.net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, effects

Last few days i was trying to Flip the window when loading. i was not able to do the flipping part how ever i was able to do several window effect's unfortunately i need to flip the window when loading

for example in new version of skype when you are on call if you want to add another person to the conversation when you click on the add people button contact list will load to the current conversation window with a small flipping effect i need to incorporate same effect to my application which is developed in c# .net.

please be kind enough to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I correctly understood you want that your window will appear with some effect in the Win API functions there is a function AnimateWindow you could use it in .NET 
look at this [article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/FadePage.aspx)

and look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/FormAnimation.aspx)

Comment: highly appreciate your prompt response i found your samples while i was browsing for some sample code or find a small hint about flipping window effect how ever im sorry to say im looking forward to flipping effect.. thank you very much again ...